# How to get the most recently modified file of a certain size in a folder in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Here is the problem:

I have a folder with many text files. I want to find the file I need to parse; however, it has a different name each time so I cannot use the file name. What I know about it is that it is always 39KB (although marginally different each time, so I check for >39000 and <40000). However, there are often several files of that same size in the folder, and I would like to select the MOST recently modified one.

What I have:

```
If fNewest = "" Then
      Set fNewest = objFile
    ElseIf fNewest.DateLastModified < objFile.DateLastModified Then
      Set fNewest = objFile
    End If

    If (objFile.Size > 39000 and objFile.Size < 40000) Then
      Msgbox fNewest
    End If
```

While fNewest is returning the path to the file I want (the 39Kb file that was most recentl modified), Msgbox is being called 4 times (which is the number of occurances of a file that is 39Kb in that folder). Does anyone know how I can modify this code to correct this, or a better way to run this check?

My ultimate coal is to have a condition statement(s) as above so Msgbox is replaced with the call to the specific function that takes that file and parses it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim newest, fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(".").Files
  If f.Size > 39000 and f.Size < 40000 Then
    If IsEmpty(newest) Then
      Set newest = f
    ElseIf newest.DateLastModified < f.DateLastModified Then
      Set newest = f
    End If
  End If
Next

If Not IsEmpty(newest) Then MsgBox newest.Name
```

(I just replace `IsNull` with `IsEmpty`)

Answer (score 2):

Your nesting is off. The `MsgBox` should be outside the loop with which you iterate over the files in your folder, and the assignment should be inside the conditional that checks the file size. Try this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("...").Files
  If f.Size > 39000 and f.Size < 40000 Then
    If IsEmpty(newest) Then
      Set newest = f
    ElseIf newest.DateLastModified < f.DateLastModified Then
      Set newest = f
    End If
  End If
Next

If Not IsNull(newest) Then MsgBox newest.Name
```

Comment: Runtime error: Object required: fNewest on the line `ElseIf fNewest.DateLastModified < objFile.DateLastModified Then `...It is declared as Dim above.